# When I Take a Screen Shot of my Server with PHP exec() it returns all black

Tags: php, command-line, screenshot

ok I used a COmmandLine tool called [cmdCapture](http://www.ducklink.com/free-command-line-screen-capture.php) then ran the following Code in a PHP Script

```
exec('cmdCapture.exe /f "lol.jpg"');
```

everything looks fine.It generate a file callled lol.jpg. it outputs the filename etc etc but upon examining the lol.jpg file , its all black. If i run the Same command from windows commandline it works perfectly. Just not from inside PHP. any Ideas? 
(Running: Latest Apache & PHP on Windows 7)

Answer (score 4):

> any Ideas?

The screen is just black. E.g. the server has disabled it to "save energy", e.g. a black screensaver. That would explain why the screenshot is all black, too.

Comment: umm no.....actually its my Own PC that i'm running ri8 now! its awake & Alive :) now any Ideas?

Comment: Ensure that the capture application has the needed rights to obtain the handle of the screen to capture it. Some GDI+ / bitblit operations that fail result in a blank (black) image. So check that the program you're using is invoked correctly, has the required ACL settings and is compatible with your operating system.